# Run Application_Start immediately when application pool/Application restarts in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, iis

What I want is that my Application_Start in Global.asax (Or any other piece of code) runs automatically whenever application pool/Application restarts in IIS. Application_Start gets triggered on the first request but I don't want to wait for the first request, but I want to do something whenever my Web API is deployed and started.

So, Is there any way via code (Not at IIS Level) that can achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure but you can try set "Start Mode = Always Running" for your application pool.

Edit 1: This should enforce IIS to directly load/reload your application pool and thus triggering Application_Start of your Global.asax

---

Edit 2

Just to make it clear, this is what i meant.
[image]

1. Go to application pools
2. Right Click your application pool
3. Go to advanced settings
4. Change OnDemand to AlwaysRunning

Yes this is not code based. But as of I know you have to configure application pool to achieve what you want.

Maybe you want to check this too (contains samples for code based app pool configuration): [Application Pool Defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults/)

Comment: Not Sure which "Start Mode = Always Running" you are referring to. Do you mean "Start Application pool immediately" option in Basic settings of an App Pool. That doesn't help me as it doesn't trigger the App_Start. PLease let me know if you are referring to any other specific option in IIS App pool.

Comment: Go to "Applications Pools >> (your app pool) >> Advanced Settings >> General". There you can set application pool start mode.

Comment: If you are referring to "Start Automatically" which can be set to True/False. This doesn't fire any event. Infact it enables the API to Accept request at any time where the First request will fire Application_Start. Your comments please

Comment: I updated my answer. Check the edit 2 section above. Hopefully this helps

Comment: I think what you have said is what I wanted. However I do not see that option in my App Pool Advanced settings, maybe i am missing some IIS module. Any idea?

Comment: Got that. It's available in IIS 8 but I am using IIS 7. so no luck it seems.

Comment: Links for answer:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2013/01/25/application-initialization-ui-for-iis-7-5/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/09/iis-8-whats-new-application-pool-settings/
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization#additionalDownloads
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults/